# Hip pain out of the saddle

Tags: training, pain

I am getting hip pain (both sides) when climbing hills out of the saddle. I am conscious to not choose too higher gear to get my cadence right but I end up back in the saddle spinning as they get so sore. Any thoughts? My quads are fine and when I use the spin bike to practice out of the saddle, this doesn't happen. 
Happy for any help as training for a short triathlon and need to get my riding right. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When do you experience this pain?  Immediately, after several minutes, or after the ride or when?  Is the pain definitely in the muscles, or could it be in the joints?

Comment: Just as a suggestion, until we narrow down what the syndrome may be, you might want to go to an interval training scheme where you do 30 seconds out of the saddle, then 2-3 minutes spinning, then repeat.  This stresses the muscles involved (to "train" them), but then gives them a chance to recover before they reach the "breaking point" where they are in trouble metabolically.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I think that is a great idea. I will definitely try that. The pain is pretty straight away once I am out of the saddle and backs off afterwards. I have existing bursitis in my hip joints and it wasn't until the cold has set in, in Central Vic, Australia that it has bothered me. I have done a pile of rehab to strengthen these joints.

Comment: So does the pain seem to be bursitis, or does it seem to originate from the muscles?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I believe its from the bursitis. I ride again tomorrow and am going to mark the pain spot as I see my physio the next day and hoping she can tell me where its originating from. On my last training ride, I tried the interval idea which worked well as the pain really starts to get going after the 30 sec so its a good place to stop and I didn't loose much speed. Will get back to you after Friday. Thanks again

Comment: Good to hear that interval training seems to help.  But note that you really want the intervals to be short enough to NOT produce pain, but stop something short of that point.

Answer (score 1):

I think this hip pain is an indication of fatique, which will diminish through ptactice.

I experienced this once.

I had been cycling for more than 20 years and was skillful with out-of-saddle ride.  I did this every now and then for say less than 1 km for fun.

Last September I challenged myself to a total of 10 km climbs (8 discontinous climbs stretched over 36 km) out of saddle. The gradients varied from 5 to 10.

The following morning my hip joints hurt.  Then I realized it was fatigue.

After a week I rode the same route again to test.  This time there was no more fatigue.

I think practise and rest and practise, and the pain will go.  My experience.

Comment: Hi and thanks for all comments. After visiting my physio, she informed me that she believes that I am overworking my piriformis muscle. She was really pleased with the interval training and also thought that fatigue would be a factor. I have been doing the hills towards the end of the training ride so I will put them in earlier. She also suggested turning my knees out very slightly when out of the saddle to take the pressure off the piriformis. I am going to practice all these things and see if I can manage it better. Any further advice always welcome. Many thanks again